# How to hide an element and still be able to transition it and also have something sticky inside it?

Tags: javascript, css

On button press, I am trying to unhide `pads_and_pool` element by transitioning its height from 0 to `pads` element's height.

At the same time, I want the `pool` element to be sticky, hence the `position: sticky` and `top: 0` on it.

However, this will not work due to the `overflow: hidden` being set on `pads_and_pool`.

Is there any other way - that would allow for stickiness - of initially hiding the `pads_and_pool` element and still being able to transition it to desired height upon button press?

Preferably, I would like to avoid changing the overflow to `scroll` or removing the `pool` element from the flexbox.

I am looking for either CSS or JS solution.

```js
let fill_btn = document.getElementById('unhide')
fill_btn.addEventListener('click', unhide_pads_and_pool)
                    
function unhide_pads_and_pool() {
  let pads = document.getElementById('pads')
  let pads_and_pool =           document.getElementById('pads_and_pool')  
  pads_and_pool.style.height = pads.offsetHeight + 'px'                
}
```

```css
#pads_and_pool {
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: grey;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  transition: height 2s;
}
#pads {
  height: 5000px;
  width: 500px;
  background: orange;
}
#pool {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background: powderblue;
}
```

```html
<button id="unhide">Unhide pads and pool</button>
<div id="pads_and_pool">
    <div id="pads">pads</div>
    <div id="pool">pool</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could listen for the [transitionend event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/transitionend_event) and remove `overflow: hidden;` once the element has finished its height transition:

```js
let fill_btn = document.getElementById('unhide');
fill_btn.addEventListener('click', unhide_pads_and_pool);

function handleTransitionEnd(event) {
  event.target.style.overflow = 'visible';
  event.target.removeEventListener('transitionend', handleTransitionEnd);
}

function unhide_pads_and_pool() {
  let pads = document.getElementById('pads');
  let pads_and_pool = document.getElementById('pads_and_pool');
  pads_and_pool.addEventListener('transitionend', handleTransitionEnd);
  pads_and_pool.style.height = pads.offsetHeight + 'px'                
}
```

```css
#pads_and_pool {
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: grey;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  transition: height 2s;
}
#pads {
  height: 5000px;
  width: 500px;
  background: orange;
}
#pool {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background: powderblue;
}
```

```html
<button id="unhide">Unhide pads and pool</button>
<div id="pads_and_pool">
    <div id="pads">pads</div>
    <div id="pool">pool</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a great solution, because it will work when there is a div below the one expaned.

Answer (score 1):

position sticky will not work if the element has parents (direct/indirect) that has overflow property set other than the default value (visible).

[From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

> This value always creates a new stacking context. Note that a sticky element "sticks" to its nearest ancestor that has a "scrolling mechanism" (created when overflow is hidden, scroll, auto, or overlay), even if that ancestor isn't the nearest actually scrolling ancestor. This effectively inhibits any "sticky" behavior (see the Github issue on W3C CSSWG).

So my proposed solution is to just change the overflow value to the default one which is **visible** once you unhide the container.

```js
let fill_btn = document.getElementById('unhide')
fill_btn.addEventListener('click', unhide_pads_and_pool)
                    
function unhide_pads_and_pool() {
  let pads = document.getElementById('pads')
  let pads_and_pool =           document.getElementById('pads_and_pool')  
  pads_and_pool.style.height = pads.offsetHeight + 'px';
  pads_and_pool.style.overflow = 'visible';              
}
```

```css
#pads_and_pool {
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: grey;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  transition: height 2s;
}
#pads {
  height: 5000px;
  width: 500px;
  background: orange;
}
#pool {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background: powderblue;
}
```

```html
<button id="unhide">Unhide pads and pool</button>
<div id="pads_and_pool">
    <div id="pads">pads</div>
    <div>
      <div id="pool">pool</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is good, but will cause some unpleasant effect when there is also a div below the one expanded. Hence I will mark the other solution as best one, but upvoting yours!